# C# Google Chrome Extension, where is my bin/debug path?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google Chrome Extension and I need add a library to my project.

I know how can I add the library but there is a problem I have.

First, I added .dll file into my referance.

Than, I need a debug folder in my bin folder. Normally, bin/debug file create automatically when you create new project in C#. But when I create "Chrome extensions project" the file path didn't create. I created manually but it didn't worked.

I created a console app and I tried add my library into the project, it worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `bin\debug` folder in the *Google Chrome Extension* project. The output is the `zip` file (not `dll` or `exe`), that contains the files from the `app` directory. You register this `zip` file as an extension.

You can't build Chrome extension using c#.

More info you can find here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c11cd639-2abb-4243-96d2-153c0adb494a

Comment: It's not completely impossible to use C# in a Chrome Extension, but it would nee to be a separate project / application. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: @Xan That's right, you can use https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage, but, as you said, it should be a separate project of type other than *Google Chrome Extension*.

Comment: Another remark: `xpi` is for Firefox extensions (including WebExtensions). For Chrome Web Store, you just need the zip. Corresponding format for Chrome itself, `crx`, is something more than just a zip.